# Converting Google Cloud Vision OCR X and Y Co-ordinates to bbox Co-ordinates

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision, hocr

Google Cloud Vision OCR has the following Output for a bounding box Object.

```
vertices {
  x: 786
  y: 967
}
```

## Desired Output Format for Bounding Box

I want to go ahead and convert these co-ordinates to bounding box co-ordinates to write them in my hOCR format.
Which includes the following format for writing those in the file.

```
  <span class='ocr_line' title="bbox 348 797 1482 838; baseline -0.009 -6">
```

### Questions?

- ***So how can I convert these x and y co-ordinates to these bbox (Bounding Box Co-ordinates).***
- **What are these `x` and `y` co-ordinates is it (`x_min`, `y_max`) or (`x_max`, `y_min`). In general I want to also know what do these x and y represent?**

## Working on Image

I am working on the following image as my test.

[image: Test Image]

Comment: two values aren't a box, they're a *point*. you don't have enough information to make a box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As informed by @Christoph Rackwitz in the coments, this value is just a point. Each letter will be  indicated by a set of 4 of this points, creating a bbox, like the following:

```json
{
          "description": "وأما",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 1088,
                "y": 230
              },
              {
                "x": 1145,
                "y": 230
              },
              {
                "x": 1145,
                "y": 289
              },
              {
                "x": 1088,
                "y": 289
              }
            ]
          }
        },
```

And the entire Page will be on the first object, as following:

```json
        {
          "locale": "ar",
          "description": "وأما ثانيا : فلأنه يخرج منه من زنی مثلا ثم جب ذكرة فإنه\nلا يتأتی\nمنه غير الندم على ما مضی ، وأما العزم على عدم\nقال : إن الندم\nيكفي في حد التوبة ، وليس كما قال ؛ لانه لو ندم ولم يقلع\nوعزم على العود لم يكن تائبا اتفاقا ، قال : وقال بعض المحق قين :\nاختيار ترك ذنب سبق حقيقة. أو تقديرا لأجل ال له قال :\nالعود فلا يتصور منه ، قال : وبهذا اغتر من\nهي\nوهذا أسد العبارات وأجمعها لأن التائب لا يكون تار کا\nل لذنب الذي فرغ لأنه غير متمكن من عينه لا تركا ولا فعلا ،\nمثله حقيقة ، وكذا من لم يقع منه ذنب\nمتمكن\nوإنما هو\nمن\nإنما يصح منه اتقاء ما يمكن أن يقع لا ترك مثل ما وقع فيكون\nمتقيا لا تائبا ، قال : والباعث على هذا تنبيه إلهي لمن أراد\nمهلك يفوث على\nلأنه\nسم\nسعادته لقبح الذنب وضر ره ؛\nالإنسان سعادة الدنيا والآخرة ويحجبة عن معرفة ال له. تعالي في\nالدنيا ، وعن تقريبه في الآخرة\nقال : ومن تفقد نفسه وجدها مشحونة بهذا السم فإذا وفق\nانبعث منه خوف هجوم الهلاك عليه ، فيبادر بطلب ما يدفع\n",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 122,
                "y": 223
              },
              {
                "x": 1197,
                "y": 223
              },
              {
                "x": 1197,
                "y": 1688
              },
              {
                "x": 122,
                "y": 1688
              }
            ]
          }
        },
```

- You can process the json with the 4 points to generate the object you need.
- Check [this page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22TEXT_DETECTION%22%7D%5D%2C%22image%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%7B%22imageUri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2F9MXec.jpg%22%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D), where you can Try the API. I have used the image `url` of the upload on stack overflow as the image source (i.e `"imageUri": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MXec.jpg"`)

Comment: How do you go ahead and convert the google cloud vision python api response to a json response like this one? Code to my script is https://gist.github.com/UBISOFT-1/f00e4d22790f4af378d70b237fa56ca9 check function detect_text_document

Comment: Take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/dinosauria123/gcv2hocr), here is the code for this conversion. It might solve this issue.